# Plugin Doesn't Enqueue Script or Style - Custom Query

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins, load

I am using the Pro Blog Design plugin found [here](https://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/). It's adds a button to load more content. It is working well on my archive and search page, but does not work at all on a custom page (ex: "page-customname.php").

The custom page also has a custom query loop with pagination:

```
<?php $the_query = array('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'category_name' => 'stories');

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$the_query['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $the_query );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

// Output custom query loop
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();

   echo 'loop items go here';   

endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
  ?>
```

At the end of this loop is the plugin pagination, again, working well on archive and search, but not on the custom query page.

I can tell that the script and style do not get enqueued, because the plugin css style is not working (on this page only).

Is there any reason why this might be?

Here is the plugin function:

```
function pbd_alp_init() {
    global $wp_query;

    // Add code to index pages.
    if( !is_singular() ) {  
        // Queue JS and CSS
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'pbd-alp-load-posts',
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/load-posts.js',
            array('jquery'),
            '1.0',
            true
        );

        wp_enqueue_style(
            'pbd-alp-style',
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css',
            false,
            '1.0',
            'all'
        );

        // What page are we on? And what is the pages limit?
$max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

// Add some parameters for the JS.
wp_localize_script(
    'pbd-alp-load-posts',
    'pbd_alp',
    array(
        'startPage' => $paged,
        'maxPages' => $max,
        'nextLink' => next_posts($max, false)
    )
);
        }
 }
 add_action('template_redirect', 'pbd_alp_init');
```

**EDIT:** Updated custom query, much simpler, no `null`

```
<?php  
// Define custom query parameters
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'stories',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')));

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    

echo 'loop stuff';  

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

**EDIT: Working Solution!**

The problem was in the javascript. `!is_singular()` needed to change to something that wouldn't negate the custom page, ex: `!is_home();`

Also, the javascript wouldn't recognize the query or its associated page numbers, so I had to change `$global wp_query` to `$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish'));` which might not be the best solution, but it seems to work across all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if( !is_singular() ) {` evaluates to TRUE on archive and search pages because those pages do not display a singular resource (is_singular() returns false and then is negated by leading "!"). So the code in that if block is never being run on your page because is_singular evaluates to TRUE and then is negated by "!".

Comment: The archive and search pages are the only places where it is working though.

Comment: right, if is_singluar() returns false on those pages then !is_singular evaluates to true and runs the code. I see where my wording is confusing. I will update.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, so if I change it to `is_singular()` without the exclamation point, or even if I change it to something like `!is_home()` it still does not work on my custom page. `!is_home()` still works on archive and search.

Comment: is_singular works off the $wp_query global, it's possible that your setting it to null is affecting the result of the function.

Comment: Thanks, I removed those two lines `$wp_query   = NULL;` and also `$temp_query = $wp_query;`  Pagination still works, but the plugin still does not, unfortunately.

Comment: For simplicity's sake, I changed my loop query. Edit above. Pagination still works, but plugin still does not :(

Comment: Ok, even if this works I don't think that it is a longterm solution, but what happens when you remove the if (!is_singular) block from around the rest of the code?

Comment: Alrighty, I removed the if statement completely. Still works on archive and search. No change on custom page. I find this super confusing.

Comment: Ok, interesting. Would you mind sharing the html output for the page where it is not working? If it seems too big for here you code post in https://codeshare.io/ and reply with link.

Comment: Glad you asked me to do that. It appears the plugin stylesheet and javascript are actually being output. My placeholder html was wrong, which is why it wasn't getting the css. [Code found here](https://jsfiddle.net/casslt07/Lormq4o9/)

Comment: It seems that the reason the javascript side of the plugin isn't working has something to do with the line `if(pageNum <= max) { /*implement plugin*/}`  I'm marking your answer correct since you have solved my initial question, thank you!